# Wrong delete statment in case when object is updated

Tags: java, hibernate

in my scenario I have 2 tables: album and image (relationship is one to many).

Here is simplified mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Album" table="album">
    <id name="id" column="album_id" type="int">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">TestObject_seq</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <set name="image" table="image" order-by="orderBy">
        <key column="album_id" />
        <composite-element class="Image">
            <property name="caption" column="caption" type="string"/>
            <property name="path" column="path" type="string"/>
            <property name="orderBy" column="orderBy" type="int"/>
        </composite-element>
    </set>  
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am doing this:
1. find object in db,
2. delete some records from collection,
3. call saveOrUpdate.

```
Album album = dao.getAlbum("Name of album");

Set<Image> imagesToRemove = getImagesToRemove();
album.getImages().removeAll(imagesToRemove);

dao.saveOrUpdate(album);
dao.flushAndClear();
```

Everything is ok till the moment that some values in table image are null. For example caption has null value.

In log I can see:

```
DEBUG SQL:292 - delete from image where album_id=? and caption=? and path=? and orderBy=?
DEBUG AbstractBatcher:343 - preparing statement
DEBUG IntegerType:59 - binding '463' to parameter: 1
DEBUG StringType:52 - binding null to parameter: 2
...
```

In this case delete statement won't delete any record.

What I am doing wrongly?

Comment: does your query give you any error messages or anything?

Comment: No, any messages nor errors. Delete statement is executable but nothing is deleted. 
If the same sql statement is used as is printed in log, then "caption=null" will be never satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are not deleting orphans. When you are updating object by deleting entities they exists in database as orphans.
Try using this.

```
<set name="image" table="image" cascade="all-delete-orphan" order-by="orderBy">
    <key column="album_id" ></key>
    <composite-element class="Image">
        <property name="caption" column="caption" type="string"/>
        <property name="path" column="path" type="string"/>
        <property name="orderBy" column="orderBy" type="int"/>
    </composite-element>
 </set>
```

Comment: I don't think. If I am removing any object from collection, calling of saveOrUpdate will synchronize this changes with db. In case when all fields have different value than null, it will delete them.

Comment: So I have tested it with property cascade="all-delete-orphan". The result is same, nothing have been deleted (delete statement is same as before).

Comment: I think I found the reason:
`A composite element mapping does not support null-able properties if you are using a <set>. There is no separate primary key column in the composite element table. Hibernate uses each column's value to identify a record when deleting objects, which is not possible with null values. You have to either use only not-null properties in a composite-element or choose a <list>, <map>, <bag> or <idbag>.` 
[link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/components.html) 

I switched to bag and seems everything ok, except additional statements.